# Can't get objects to align at the bottom of divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get a row of five images to display, aligned at the bottom at different scales. I've got the sizes to work but for some reason everything I try to get them to sit at the bottom doesn't work. The scaling is correct but I just can't get them to sit at the bottom. I've tried float, vertical align, position, bottom: 0px... Stumped.. Do I need to wrap the, in another div!?

Thanks for your help!

```
    <html>

<style>
.photos {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -moz-column-gap:      0px;
  column-count:         5;
  column-gap:           0px;
  height: 500px;
  float: bottom;
}

.one {
  width: 40% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  object-fit:     fill;
  float: bottom;
}

.two {
  width: 70% !important;
  height: 500px !important;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.four {
  width: 65% !important;
  height: 500px !important;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.six {
  width: 95% !important;
  height: 500px !important;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.eight {
  width: 95% !important;
  height: 500px !important;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

</style>

<div class="photos">

<img class="one" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0088/3094/3290/files/One_10_editors_award_e72e0a9f-af53-4d5a-a7ff-ad43529a292e.PNG?16373459996811127802">

<img class ="two" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0088/3094/3290/files/TWO-10-500sq.png?16128425807283382807">

<img class="four" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0088/3094/3290/files/FOUR-10-800-colour-corrected-800.png?161284258072833828077">

<img class="six" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0088/3094/3290/files/Six_main_WEB.jpg?16128425807283382807">


<img class="eight" align="botoom" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0088/3094/3290/files/EIGHT-10.png?16128425807283382807">

</div>
```

Comment: There is no such property value as `float:bottom`. What is this supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good css property that would fit perfectly in your case is using the display: flex property.

Setting the .photo class as a flex container like this:

```
    .photo {  display: flex; }
```

then add a align property to the .photo class to set a align to all of its direct  children:

```
.photo {  align-items: flex-end ; }
```

Or if you want to add separately on each class then use the css property align-self

```
.one{  align-self: flex-end; }

.two{  align-self: flex-end; }
```

...etc

More info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/